# REGEX to validate password that can't contain some caracters

Tags: php, regex, passwords

I need to check if a password match the following rules:

- At least 8 characters (lenth)
- One capital letter
- One lower letter
- One number
- One special char
- Can't contain '.' or '_' (tricky part)

For example:

- Bft$ns2E      => should match
- H2od%^.,3     => should't match (notice the '.')

I tried this:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){1,})(?!.*\s).{8,}$
```

That satisfy all rules, except the last one ( Can't contain '.' or '_'). Regex are always a pain for me and can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks to all!

Comment: If your struggling with the regex - why carry on with it.  It's not as though it's code that will be run loads of times so even if it's slower to split it out, it may be more maintainable.

Comment: I use an api and a back-end and I want to validate the password in both sites, i dont want to repeat a validation function in each lenguajes, I think is better to use a ragex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is on the right track.  I would use:

```regex
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)(?!.*[._]).{8,}$
```

This pattern says to:

```regex
^
    (?=.*?[A-Z])  assert capital letter
    (?=.*[a-z])   assert lowercase letter
    (?=.*\d)      assert digit
    (?=.*\W)      assert non word/special character
    (?!.*[._])    assert NO dot or underscore
    .{8,}         match a password of length 8 or greater
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the lookaheads like this `(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})`, you can omit the group with the quantifier `{1,}` as asserting it once in the string is enough.

If you don't want to match a space `.` or `_` you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match 8 or more times excluding those characters.

Using a negated character class as well in the lookahead assertions prevents unnecessary backtracking.

```
^(?=[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z\r\n]*[a-z])(?=[^\d\r\n]*\d)(?=\w*\W)[^\s._]{8,}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])` Assert  a char A-Z
- `(?=[^a-z\r\n]*[a-z])` Assert a char a-z
- `(?=[^\d\r\n]*\d)` Assert a digit
- `(?=\w*\W)` Assert a non word char
- `[^\s._]{8,}` Match 8+ times any char except a whitespace char `.` or `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rkK4Tt/1)